# Mac user name is causing irritations

Tags: iso

My Desktop Mac is about four years old. I don't remember the original OS but it has been upgraded to Yosemite. At the time of purchase / original setup I don't remember what user accounts I set up. It may have been my name only Simon xxxx or it may have been my wife only Lesleyxxxx or both. I seem to remember setting up a guest account. At some point early on I imported lesley's iTunes. After a year or so of being totally confused about who's iTunes was doing what and who's mac it was "lesley's Mac" / "Simons Mac" I decided to delete her user account & iTunes. I was then either left with "guest" and Simon xxxx or "guest"  and created "Simon xxxx" making simon the administrator. The problem or rather annoyance I now have is the name lesleyxxxx appears randomly from time to time. For example I have just set up an airport extreme & Mac TV both seem to be called "lesley's". In my user groups the only users appearing are guest and Simon xxxx. However, on opening the Terminal the first two lines read: Last login DATE TIME on ttys000 Simon-Desktop:~lesleyxxxx$. Note the title bar on opening the Terminal has a house symbol followed by lesleyxxxx – bash –No X No. At login or on the top right of the screen the only name mentioned is Simon xxxx. How can I stop the lesleyxxxx appearing as it is.

Answer (score 1):

At one time you must have used "`lesleyxxx`" as administrator account.

Terminal shows "`Simon-Desktop:~lesleyxxxx$`"

Simon-Desktop is the name you gave it in the system preferences- Sharing (you can change it there.

the ~lesleyxxxx part shows you are using a home directory called ~lesleyxxxx.

That is because you are logged in as ~lesleyxxxx!- Change that in Users & Groups.

You can also delete other users but be aware they settings will be deleted as well.

Comment: Thank you Buscar. Your answer pointed me in the right direction which lead me here http://support.apple.com/en-ae/HT201548 It took a couple of goes but now everything is all working and named as it should be. As a bonus my mouse is now working much faster as well??

Comment: Great it worked for you! it can be confusing with User name, Account Name, Home folder Name ...